# Tool/script that can expand all 'include' directives in a makefile

Tags: scripting, make

Let us say we have the following `Makefile`

```
include config.mk

# Generate summary table.
results.txt : $(ZIPF_SRC) isles.dat abyss.dat last.dat
    $(ZIPF_EXE) *.dat > $@

# Count words.
.PHONY : dats
dats : isles.dat abyss.dat last.dat

%.dat : books/%.txt $(COUNT_SRC)
    $(COUNT_EXE) $< $*.dat

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f *.dat
    rm -f results.txt
```

where all the variables are defined in `config.mk`

```
LANGUAGE=python
COUNT_SRC=countwords.py
COUNT_EXE=$(LANGUAGE) $(COUNT_SRC)
ZIPF_SRC=testzipf.py
ZIPF_EXE=$(LANGUAGE) $(ZIPF_SRC)
```

Is there any tool available that can expand all the `include` lines within the `makefile` so as to produce a `bigMakefile`? If such a tool does not currently exist, can a `python/perl/awk/bash` script be cooked up to achieve this goal?

Comment: With GNU Make, `make -qprR` will dump all the variables and rules loaded as a result of processing the main Makefile and all included files, along with the environment variables. I suspect it would need quite a lot of post-processing to meet your requirements...

Comment: @StephenKitt I think `-qprR` diverges a lot (and almost an overkill) for my  requirements which needlessly increases post-processing complexity. I just need a simple in-place expansion of the `include` line. Can an `awk` script do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GNU Awk manual's section on getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile) has an almost perfect example:

> For example, the following program copies all the input files to the
>   output, except for records that say `@include filename`. Such a record
>   is replaced by the contents of the file filename:
>
> ```
> {
>      if (NF == 2 && $1 == "@include") {
>           while ((getline line < $2) > 0)
>                print line
>           close($2)
>      } else
>           print
> }
> ```

You just need to modify it to match `include` instead of `@include`.

Comment: Awesome. That just works. Thanks a lot for the brilliant suggestion.

Comment: what if the file is actually a macro, as in  `include $(foo)`? what about the `ifdef`s, `ifeq`s? what about `include *.mk`?

Comment: @pizdelect these are all valid cases to be accounted for a generic makefile parser. But my question was about a specific case, and the accepted answer above tackles just that!

Comment: It's great that you're happy with the answer, but this is public place and other people may wish to know all the pitfalls and limitations of this approach, and if  @muru won't mention them, I'll happily do it for him, no matter if he find my help welcome or not.